# how to search string in Linq to SQL using contains

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am using below code to search a particular string in multiple columns

```
IEnumerable<UserProductDetailResult> _query
    = from eml in dc.UserProductDetails
      join zk in dc.ZeekUsers on eml.aspnet_User.UserId equals zk.UserId
      where eml.aspnet_User.LoweredUserName.Equals(strUserName.ToLower())
         && (eml.Username.Contains(strSearch)
             || eml.ProductURL.Contains(strSearch)
             || eml.Nickname.Contains(strSearch))
         && !eml.IsDeleted
         && eml.IsActive
      select new UserProductDetailResult
          {
            _userProductDetail = eml,
            _zeekUser = zk
          };
```

where dc is DataContext object.

but this returns 0 results.

the query that is generated from above code is

```
SELECT [t0].[UPID], [t0].[UserId], [t0].[PID], [t0].[Nickname], [t0].[Username], [t0].[ProductURL], [t0].[StartDt], [t0].[EndDt], [t0].[IsActive], [t0].[InfoData], [t0].[SocialNetworkingData], [t0].[AnalyticKey], [t0].[ProfileID], [t0].[UseDefaultAd], [t0].[UseDefaultEmail], [t0].[IsDeleted], [t0].[CreateDt], [t0].[LastUpdateDt], [t1].[ID], [t1].[UserId] AS [UserId2], [t1].[AccountType], [t1].[FirstName], [t1].[LastName], [t1].[Phone], [t1].[Address1], [t1].[Address2], [t1].[City], [t1].[State], [t1].[ZIP], [t1].[CountryID], [t1].[NickName1], [t1].[Nickname2], [t1].[AlternameEmail], [t1].[ProfileImage], [t1].[ZeekIdStatus], [t1].[RefZeekUserId], [t1].[IsActive] AS [IsActive2], [t1].[FailureCount], [t1].[IsBlocked], [t1].[IsFirstVisit], [t1].[IsWizardPassed], [t1].[IPAddress], [t1].[TimeZoneID], [t1].[CreateDt] AS [CreateDt2], [t1].[LastUpdateDt] AS [LastUpdateDt2]
FROM [dbo].[UserProductDetails] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ZeekUsers] AS [t1] ON ((
    SELECT [t2].[UserId]
    FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[UserId] = [t0].[UserId]
    )) = [t1].[UserId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[aspnet_Users] AS [t3] ON [t3].[UserId] = [t0].[UserId]
WHERE ([t3].[LoweredUserName] = 'username') AND (([t0].[Username] LIKE 'a') OR ([t0].[ProductURL] LIKE 'a') OR ([t0].[Nickname] like 'a')) AND (NOT ([t0].[IsDeleted] = 1)) AND ([t0].[IsActive] = 1)
```

As soon as remove below search lines it works and returns ,

```
&& (eml.Username.Contains(strSearch)
    || eml.ProductURL.Contains(strSearch)
    || eml.Nickname.Contains(strSearch))
```

but this doesn't allow me to search

Can anyone please tell me how should I proceed?

Comment: Give an example of a search string and potential values that you expect to be found.

Comment: if i enter search = "a" then it should return all the rows for which either of Username, ProductURL,Nickname has "a" in it irrespective of the case and word equivalent to '%a%' in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

By your generated query, I think you are using the `linq-to-sql`. You could use the [SqlMethods.Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx) to generate the right `like` query operator, from MSDN:

> Determines whether a specific character string matches a specified
>   pattern. This method is currently only supported in LINQ to SQL
>   queries.

For sample:

```
// first sample, any part of string
strSearch = string.Format("%[^a-zA-Z]{0}[^a-zA-Z]%", strSearch);

// on the end of the string
strSearch = string.Format("%[^a-zA-Z]{0}", strSearch);

//on the begining of the string
strSearch = string.Format("{0}[^a-zA-Z]%", strSearch);
```

in your query statemant..

```
(SqlMethods.Like(eml.Username, strSearch) 
|| SqlMethods.Like(eml.ProductURL, strSearch) 
|| SqlMethods.Like(eml.Nickname, strSearch))
```

Otherwise you could add the `%` char in your `strSearch` string before your query to result a query with information in any part of string, for sample:

```
strSearch = string.Contat("%", strSearch, "%");
```

Comment: @Felipe... its not working... If I use ToUpper() in both search as well as Columns then it works... Can you suggest something which will not consider case?

Answer (score 1):

I have create a nuget package that can help you here.  It will enable you to use the following syntax:

```
var result = dc.UserProductDetails
               .Where(eml => eml.IsActive && !eml.IsDeleted)
               .Search(eml => eml.aspnet_User.LoweredUserName) // Search LoweredUsername
               .IsEqual(strUserName)                           // when equals strUsername
               .Search(eml => eml.UserName,                    // Search UserName
                       eml => eml.ProductURL,                  // OR ProductUrl
                       eml => eml.Nickname)                    // OR Nickname
               .Containing(strSearch)                          // When contains strSearch
               .Select(eml => new UserProductDetailResult      // Build result...
                              {
                                   _userProductDetail = eml
                              });
```

You can download the package from here

### http://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions

...also take a look at the [GitHub page](https://github.com/ninjanye/SearchExtensions) for more detailed information

Hope this helps